# Cannot set bounty

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounty

I tried adding a bounty to my question [Changing OOB content types on selected lists](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11818/changing-oob-content-types-on-selected-lists)
However I see no link below comments (like specified here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to set a bounty even though I clearly have enough rep.

I do see one featured question though, so I guess it **is** possible?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question si just 1 hour old (at the time of writing this post)Give it 48 hours and you will see the link. from : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties

> The question has been asked in the
>   last 48 hours. Give the community a
>   chance to answer your question
>   normally first.

Comment: ahhh you mean I actually have to **read** the links i refer to? ;-)

Comment: he he .. yh in short Yes :-)